# Why do I always get an SQLException with this setup?

Tags: java, jdbc

> **Not a duplicate** of the above-linked question, because the linked answer does everything I did in this question. My solution involves some outside-code changes, but no answer elaborates on this.

I read many other posts on StackOverflow, and tutorials around the web, on how to use Java to create a local database. As far as I can tell from those, I'm doing this all correctly:

```
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "password";
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=" + USER + "&password=" + PASS;

private final String DB_NAME;

public MyDBClass(String subName) {
    DB_NAME = "`SOOT " + subName + "`";
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;

    try {
        Class.forName(java.sql.Driver.class.getName()); // Line 38

        Logger.getGlobal().finer("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); // Line 41

        Logger.getGlobal().finer("Creating database...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_NAME
                + " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8"
                + " DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not create database.", ex);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=password
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at my.app.MyDBClass.<init>(MyDBClass.java:41)
    at my.app.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

I tried using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` instead of `Class.forName(java.sql.Driver.class.getName());` on line 38, but I got:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at my.app.MyDBClass.<init>(Language.java:38)
    at my.app.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Comment: Did you download the JDBC driver for MySQL?

Comment: What is the `SQLException` you're getting?

Comment: @MaxZoom I never saw that as a step... could you elaborate?

Comment: @Ben Follow the [white rabbit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/4454454)

Comment: @MaxZoom oh, so I can't just use SQL as my app's way of storing data? The user has to have it installed on their computer first?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use mysql, as it's a server. You can use a different JDBC driver though, such as [a wrapper for sqlite](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), which does not need a server.

Comment: Thanks, all. I guess I'll just use a series of `.properties` or `.json` files.

Comment: Some of these would make good answers if y'all wanna post them!